# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while reading from dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scalatest, embedded-kafka

I'm working on scala streaming unit test but while reading from csv file getting ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Code :

```
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers
import org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

class StreamingTest extends AnyWordSpecLike with Matchers {

val sparkses  = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp").config("spark.master","local").getOrCreate()

val df = sparkses.read.format("csv").load("file.csv")
df.printSchema()

}
```

The code works fine without extending AnyWordSpecLike with Matchers, but we need it to work with EmbeddedKafka.
Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Malformed csv? Like some rows having less columns than others?

Comment: No, it has only 2 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: Reading the dataframe in the constructor seems smelly. That is probably your problem. Hard to tell for sure though without seeing the stack trace for the exception.